# Conditional Output Caching in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, asp.net-mvc-4, outputcache

I have an MVC application that I want to cache an Action's output for, but conditionally based off of business logic. But I'm not having much luck, I know about the CacheOutputAttribute, but it's a static rule.

Specifically I have a document table used to store binary data for an intranet site. And when the document type being served is an image, I want to allow the browser to cache the file so it doesn't need to request it every single time.

I've tried the following but have not had any luck getting the browser to recognize the asset as cacheable.

```
public ActionResult View(Guid id)
{
    /*
        get document from database
    */
    switch (document.ContentType)
    {
        case "image/jpeg":
        case "image/tiff":
        case "image/x-png":
        case "image/png":
        case "image/gif":
            Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30));
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Private);
            Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(true); 
            break;
    }
    return File(document.Data, document.ContentType);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't want to use OutputCache for example using VaryByParam?

Try this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute(v=vs.108).aspx

and this

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs

Comment: Or you can use VaryByCustom property. Usage you can find here http://www.dhuvelle.com/2011/09/aspnet-mvc-custom-outputcache-with.html

Comment: `VaryByParam` assumes that my criteria is a parameter of the request, which it's not in this case. My logic depends on the document type which I obtain from the database using the documentId parameter. `VaryByCustom` is close, but it depends upon a single function that you place in the `global.asax` (based on what you linked). While I could hack something together using that it seems that if I ever add a second page that has conditional caching I'm going to have fun trying to maintain that function in `global.asax`.